# how to count data in database base on input?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I want to count how many monitor or desktop there is in item code how can i do it? please help me

My Form:
[image: My Form]

My Database:
[image: My Database]

My Code:
[image: My Code]

Comment: please include your code here, as text, not an image on another site.

Comment: i don't see a column "code" in your table. remember: `"code" != "item_code"`

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(code) from controlnumber where code='MONITOR';
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `in`

```
select count(item_code) from controlnumber where code in ('MONITOR','DESKTOP');
```